# Is it safe to use HTTPS provided automatically by Glitch although I've only setup an HTTP express app?

Tags: javascript, express, http, security, https

I have created a simple http express app and uploaded it on glitch.

The code is as follows:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(express.static('./views'));

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

When I choose view app on a new window option in glitch, the url is "**[https://some-server-name.glitch.me/**"](https://some-server-name.glitch.me/**%22)

Though I have setup only **HTTP** protocol, I get **HTTPS** in url. Does this mean it is secure to use this website ?

Comment: HTTPS is typically terminated by a reverse proxy in front of your application server. You wouldn’t want to have to care about handling HTTPS in node. If you can access the URL via HTTPS, then yes, that’s secure up to the Glitch endpoint, which is the most important part of the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is typically terminated by a reverse proxy in front of your application server. You wouldn’t want to have to care about handling HTTPS in node. If you can access the URL via HTTPS, then yes, that’s secure up to the Glitch endpoint, which is the most important part of the route.

Answered by **deceze** in the comments section.
Would have been better if he had answered it directly !